# weird Mysql ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute this query:

```
    SELECT m.name 
    FROM ".table."modules as m 
    LEFT JOIN ".table."module_page as p 
    ON m.id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN ".table."pages as pa 
    ON p.pages = pa.id
    WHERE p.pages = '1' AND m.section = '2'
    ORDER BY 'm.order' ASC
```

And as you can see i order the items ascending.
But i don't know why but it outputs it like this:

```
    id    section    active    order    name
    9     2          1         1        content_starter
    10    2          1         3        Agenda
    11    2          1         2        Nieuws
    12    2          1         4        Sidebar
```

It orders it by id.
But why??

Thanks in advance!

Grtz,
Bram

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'m.order'` is a static constant, so you really have no order here. Remove the quotes from around the column name.

Comment: +1. A quoted string, such as `'m.order'`, is referred to as a "string literal" in the MySQL documentation, rather than as a "static constant".  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Comment: @spencer7593: po-tay-to, po-tah-to.

Comment: I was just pointing out what MySQL calls it (and what most relational databases call it.)  We don't typically refer to a C++ static constant string as a "literal". Nor do we typically refer to a SQL string literal as a "static constant".